# If yes, then continue. If no, then stop

Tags: if-statement, discord, discord.py

I'm making a command for my discord bot using discord.py and want to make the command. For someone to ask the other person something and if they approve the questions, continue, and if not, they stop. I really can't find that anywhere, but I know I saw it somewhere.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
    channel = message.channel
    await channel.send('Say hello!')

    def check(m):
        return m.content == 'hello' and m.channel == channel

    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    await channel.send(f'Hello {msg.author}!')
```

Comment: You might want to check out `wait_for`: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for

Comment: Can you edit your post with the code you tried?

Comment: There , I did .

Comment: Sorry, what is the error you are getting again?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question but I hope this helps:

```
@client.command()
async def yes(ctx):
    await ctx.send("do you like dogs yes/no")
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author
    while True:
        try:
            message = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=200, check=check)
            if "yes" in message.content:
                await ctx.send("you said yes")
                return
            if "no" in message.content:
                await ctx.send("you said no")
                return
            else:
                await ctx.send("invalid input")
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send("Out of Time")
            return
```